# Content view draws off the screen using scrolling Toolbar with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

What I am trying to achieve is basically [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/):

Everything works fine, apart from content view going off screen at the bottom. The layout below is Activity's layout in which I include content fragment's. Layout is working just fine in `scrolling_content_relative_layout`, but then toolbar does not get scrolling effect. If I remove `layout_behavior` on that view the content goes under `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/subcategory_spots_pager_tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrolling_content_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Content -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Content -->

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: can you add image of how it is looking after what you have tried?